# Referencing host url in settings.py

Tags: python, django

this is a really basic question, but I cannot seem to find the answer on the internet.

In settings.py I have a line that looks like this.

**settings.py**

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/profile'
```

Obviously having "localhost" is not very stable when pushing into production. And everytime I deploy it the URL changes. How to I reference the URL in settings.py?

Answer (score 2):

You should have just the endpoint in this variable and Django will take care of the rest (base URL). This can be checked [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url)

```py
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile'
```